# Detect Unicode empty value in a dictionary

Tags: python, unicode, syntax

I have something like this in a list.

```
my_arr =    [{'Brand_Name': u''}, {'Brand_Name':u''}, {'Brand_Name':u'randomstr1'}]
```

I want to be able to get all the values that are empty for brand name. In thise case I'd get two empty values. I tried this

```
for dictionary in my_arr:
    if None in dictionary:
       print dictionary
```

This doesn't work. How would I get the unicode empty value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just check for falsey values with `if not ...` (this will also include `None`, `[]`, `()`, etc)

```
>>> brands = [
        {'Brand_Name': u''},
        {'Brand_Name':u''},
        {'Brand_Name':u'randomstr1'},
    ]
>>> for brand in brands:
        if not brand['Brand_Name']:
            print brand


{'Brand_Name': u''}
{'Brand_Name': u''}
```

Comment: What if I had different dictionary names inside my arr than just Brand_Name. Wouldn't that give me other values that are empty than just Brand_Name?

Comment: @Dilli I updated the answer with your update to the question

Comment: That was helpful! Thank you!